# Null is getting set as initial value for empty string in Formik and Yup form validation in react native

Tags: react-native, formik, yup

In my simple form this is my validation Schema:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    firstName: Yup.string().required().min(2).label('First Name'),
    lastName: Yup.string().required().min(2).label('Last Name'),
    email: Yup.string("Please enter valid email address").email("Please enter valid email address").label("Email address"),
    profession: Yup.string("Please enter your profession")
});
```

And I set the initial value as empty string if the existing user is null. Like this:

```
                    initialValues={{
                        firstName: currentUser ? currentUser.firstName : "",
                        lastName: currentUser ? currentUser.lastName : "",
                        email: currentUser ? currentUser.email : "",
                        profession: currentUser ? currentUser.profession : ""
                    }}
```

And this is my FormField component which handles every input.

```
function AppFormField({ name, width, ...otherProps }) {
    const { setFieldTouched, setFieldValue, values, errors, touched } = useFormikContext();
    return (
        <>
            <AppTextInput
                onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
                onChangeText={text => setFieldValue(name, text)}
                width={width}
                value={values[name]}
                {...otherProps}
            />
            <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Everything works fine if I touch the empty fields and put something (even after make that empty later) but, If I don't touch and type anything on email or profession field and try to submit the form it gives the following error:

> Profession must be a 'string' type, but the final value was 'null'.

I don't get why the empty string was changed to null and how to work this field as optional even if touched is false.
Here is a sample screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the issue. Null was coming from the nested property. Somehow it was not ready when initializing the value. So the fix is this:

```
                        initialValues={{
                        firstName: currentUser?.firstName ? currentUser.firstName : "",
                        lastName: currentUser?.lastName ? currentUser.lastName : "",
                        email: currentUser?.email ? currentUser.email : "",
                        profession: currentUser?.profession ? currentUser.profession : ""
                    }}
```

Just also check the nested property value is null or not. That's it.